# Adding Dynamic Controls to Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am trying to add new dynamic controls on a button click but this is not adding multiple labels, also I want to retain the state of a control after postback like for adding textbox typed in value should be there.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  List<string> ControlIDs = new List<String>();
  static int count = 0;
  protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
  {
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
    ControlIDs = (List)ViewState["ControlsID"];
    foreach (string ID in ControlIDs)
    {
      count++;
      Label Dynamic_TypeinError = new Label();
      Dynamic_TypeinError.ID = ID;
      TableRow tbl_Rows = new TableRow();
      TableCell tbl_Cell = new TableCell();
      tbl_Cell.Controls.Add(Dynamic_TypeinError);
      tbl_Rows.Cells.Add(tbl_Cell);
      plc.Controls.Add(tbl_Rows);
    }
  }

  protected void Bt_AddDynamicControls_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    count++;
    Label Dynamic_TypeinError = new Label();
    Dynamic_TypeinError.ID = "Dynamic_TypeinError" + count;
    Dynamic_TypeinError.Text = "Type in Error";
    TableRow tbl_Rows = new TableRow();
    TableCell tbl_Cell = new TableCell();
    tbl_Cell.Controls.Add(Dynamic_TypeinError);
    tbl_Rows.Cells.Add(tbl_Cell);
    plc.Controls.Add(tbl_Rows);
    ControlIDs.Add(Dynamic_TypeinError.ID);
    ViewState["ControlsID"] = ControlIDs;
  }
```

Comment: you really should indent your code.

Comment: I keep looking at this and wondering how a Cell and a Row are going to work without a table.  I'm guessing you want to change how your Table renders to include the new rows not add a TableRow in dynamically without interacting with the table containing it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I am having troubles to retain the state of the dynamically added controls, lets say adding textbox instead of labels I am not able to retain the typed in data in textbox after postback.

Comment: by the way table is already added in html inside placeholder "plc", and thanks i have found the solution